# SharePoint Online (Office 365) - share invitation dailog

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker

I used the article from MSDN:

> Use the client-side People Picker control in SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-ins.

It's working perfect on a page in the site, not related to any app.
Now I want to implement it in the "share invitation" dialog, to set the schema to the exiting people picker or to hide the existing people picker and add a new one instead.

But it's not working, I'm getting error:

> Cannot read property 'SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper' of undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you trying to customise the built in share dialog, or are you creating your own custom share dialog as a part of an app?

Comment: Im trying to customise the OOB share dialog without any app just js file. Is it possible? on the other hand Im trying to add a new peoplepicker to the dialog but i have a problem to sync between both

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your code like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function () {
                //code goes here
            });
```

Looks like the sharepoint javascript file you need hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: It's still not working...same error.I saw that I need more dependencies, but If I add the files the function is not executing at all...SP.SOD.executeFunc('clienttemplates.js', 'clientforms.js', 'clientpeoplepicker.js', 'autofill.js', 'sp.RequestExecutor.js', 'sp.js', 'sp.runtime.js', 'sp.core.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function () { //my function
 }); by the example above with only 2 dependencies, the function is callled but im getting error. once I added more dependencies the function is not executed

Comment: Haven't had the requirement before to load multiple files, but I think SP.SOD.executeFunc is only suited when requesting one file. Please check this post if this helps: https://jasonscript.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/sharepoint-load-multiple/